# C: Computing a series of bits spanned over several bytes

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have got a unsigned char array of bytes like:

```
unsigned char[20] = {0xff, 0x1a, 0x70, 0xa9, ...}
```

I now want to perform computations over x consecutive bits of this array (with `x > 8`; e.g `x = 15`). In particular, I want to perform majortiy voting on every 15 bits, which returns a single bit. Subsequently, the returned single bits shall be converted to an unsigned char byte again.

I already implemented the majorityVoting algorithm. I also implemented a naive algorithm for the whole problem, which works this way:

1. Convert the byte array into a bit array (also unsigned char[] holding zeros and ones)
2. Loop over the bit array and pass every series of x bits to the majority voting function
3. Collect the majority vote results also in a bit array (unsigned char[])
4. Loop over this bit array and use bitwise operations to construct bytes from every series of 8 bits.

To me this seems intuitive but cumbersome at the same time.

Do you see any possibilities for optimization or could you even give a slicker algorithm?

Best regards,
P.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't just use 16-bit blocks having 1 unused padding bit? In fact, I would expect this is what was originally intended, with the result being stored in that 16th bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the next bit of the array with a function like that

```
 int nextBit( unsigned char [] arr, int *pByte, size_t nBytes, int *pBit ) 
 {
      int result;

      if( *pByte >= nBytes ) {
          // Padding, neccessary if nBytes % 15 != 0
          return 0;
      } else {
          result = ( arr[*pByte] >> (*pBit) ) & 0x1;
          if( *pBit == 7 ) {
              (*pByte)++;
              *pBit = 0;
          } else {
              (*pBit)++;
          }
          return result;
      }
 }
```

and loop:

```
 int byte=0, bit=0;
 int result;
 int i;

 while( byte < sizeof( arr ) ) {
     for( i=0; i<15; i++ ) {
         result = nextBit( arr, &byte, sizeof( arr ), &bit );
         // do the majority voting
     }
 }
```

A quite similar function can be created to directly create an array of the majority bits

Answer (score 0):

You could bitshift every byte into 17 bits (and store them in 17 bytes).

```
uint8_t bits[17];
bits[0] = !!(bytes[0] & 128);
bits[1] = !!(bytes[0] & 64);
bits[2] = !!(bytes[0] & 32);
bits[3] = !!(bytes[0] & 16);
bits[4] = !!(bytes[0] & 8);
bits[5] = !!(bytes[0] & 4);
bits[6] = !!(bytes[0] & 2);
bits[7] = !!(bytes[0] & 1);
bits[8] = !!(bytes[1] & 128);
bits[9] = !!(bytes[1] & 64);
bits[10] = !!(bytes[1] & 32);
bits[11] = !!(bytes[1] & 16);
bits[12] = !!(bytes[1] & 8);
bits[13] = !!(bytes[1] & 4);
bits[14] = !!(bytes[1] & 2);
bits[15] = !!(bytes[1] & 1);
bits[16] = !!(bytes[2] & 128);
```

I'm not sure about what you want to do with those bits, but you can also consider storing the bits in a 32 bit integer:

```
uint32_t chunk = (bytes[0] << 9) | (bytes[1] << 1) | (bytes[2] & 1);
```